# Is it possible to solve a system of equations for the phase of complex exponentials?

Tags: exponential-function, systems-of-equations

I have a problem which I initially thought was simple but am not so sure anymore. I'd like to solve the following system of equations

$$\alpha_1 = e^{j\mathbf{x}\theta_1} + e^{j\mathbf{x}\theta_2} + e^{j\mathbf{x}\theta_3}$$

$$\alpha_2 = e^{j\mathbf{y}\theta_1} + e^{j\mathbf{y}\theta_2} + e^{j\mathbf{y}\theta_3}$$

$$\alpha_3 = e^{j\mathbf{z}\theta_1} + e^{j\mathbf{z}\theta_2} + e^{j\mathbf{z}\theta_3}$$

where $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y},\mathbf{z}$ and each $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ are given and $\theta_{i}, i \in [1,2,3]$ are the variables to be solved for. Is there some trick to this I'm not seeing?

Comment: Do you know something about the values of $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y},\mathbf{z}$ ? I mean, beyond the fact they are given, do they satisfy some constraints like being fractions?

Comment: @Raskolnikov x,y, and z are rational numbers. But don't spend too much time on this problem, it is somewhat difficult and I have solved it already. The values of \alpha can be produced as the elements of a matrix found by multiplying Vandermonde like matrices (where the parameters are exp(j\theta_i) and the exponent powers are x,y,z). The solution is then found by performing a matrix decomposition similar to the Pisarenko Harmonic decomposition.

Comment: You can post it as an answer to your own question. I'd suggest doing that to bring closure to the question.

Comment: It will be done- though I'm writing this up as a research paper at the moment because it has an interesting application in array processing. I'll link the full paper when it's published